# How to load ajax on page loading without onclick in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I need to display ajax data when open page only, now loading ajax and display on page when onclick on anger tag. can anyone help to solve this problem?

Thank you so much

Here's my code

**Script**

```
function Generator_details(id){

    $('#Generator_details').html();
    $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Generators/get_data",
    type: 'POST',
    data:{id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:
    function(data)
    {
           document.getElementById('Id').value=data['generator_id'];
            $("#generator_serial_number").html(data['generator_serial_number']);
            $("#capacity_name").html(data['capacity_name']);


    },

    error:function(e){
    console.log("error");
    }

  });


  $('.prof_cls').removeClass('active');
    $('#Generator_detail').addClass('active');}
```

**Html**

```
<a href="#" data-page="Generator_details"   id="Generator_detail" class="list-group-item prof_cls active" onclick="return Generator_details('<?php echo $records->generator_id ?>')"><span class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></span> Generator Summary </a>


 <div class="box-body table-responsive page"  data-page="Generator_details" id="Generator_details">

    <div class="form-group clearfix">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Serial number</label>
       <label for="Serialnumber" id="generator_serial_number"></label>
       <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" id="Id">
     </div>
   </div>

 <div class="form-group clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Capacity</label>
   <label for="capacity_name" id="capacity_name"></label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is a simple php include (of a php page in another) that you are overcomplicated. Ajax is necessary only when the page has already been loaded to avoid reloading

Answer (score 0):

Call your function from document.ready by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Generator_details('<?php echo $records->generator_id ?>');
});
```

Please refer the fiddler link, in that I called the same function when loading the page and also on anchor click(For anchor click, moved the click logic to jquery instead of inline HTML event for a better practice.) This function will say "Good morning".

So likewise, whatever you write inside the function will work if your ajax logic is right.

https://jsfiddle.net/Linoy/7v9e4crj/13/

Comment: Thanks you for reply linoy, but i need to work on both condition, I need to display data when page loading and also when click on anger tag. now working only for me when click on anger tag.

Comment: Any error in browser console? If the above is worked correctly then you can retain your exiting code(no change in anchor) so both will work

Comment: not showing any error, ok linoy, but still not working when page is open, displaying data only when click on anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to call your ajax function once the page loads.

```
Generator_details(id)
```

The when you onClick to tigger the same function on your html tag

```
<button onclick="Generator_details(id)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: i tried like this, but not working, should i write any other script for display ajax data when open or loading page.